# Powering vibrator for clearing vacuum cleaner filter

Tags: motor, battery-operated, vibration, vibration-motor

[image]

I've found that one easy way of clearing the corrugated filter in many vacuum cleaners is to tap it lightly with a hammer. I suspect that using a vibrator would be more effective, and I would like to prototype such a device.

Can someone suggest what characteristics a vibrator motor should have for this    application, please? I'd probably try to package the motor in plastic with a couple of cells.

Comment: Leaving aside whether this is supposed to be a dirty joke (har har sorry) - In terms of functional attributes: Firstly the frequency. Secondly the amplitude and mass - i.e. the energy which can be transferred by each impact. Thirdly, and somewhat as a consequence of the first two, the power consumption. These will translate into motor size, type, winding details, voltage, current, and maybe there's a resonant mechanism too. Since this is something not often used, you could probably make a purely mechanical device but that's no fun. Or just use a massage-gun with the rubber head removed.

Comment: Turbine power would seem like a good idea, but off-topic here.

Comment: @PeteW: I know! I had to resort to this resource because all my attempts to find information led to pages of stuff about you-know-what.

Comment: Things that come to mind: thera-gun (massage tool), electric toothbrush, electric shaver / beard trimmer . . . especially the newest type which have this resonant mechanism almost like an electric toothbrush